# C# syntax: where TResponse, new()

Tags: c#, .net, function, syntax

```
public TResponse ExecuteCustomMessage<TResponse>(IModbusMessage request)
    where TResponse : IModbusMessage, new()
```

what is the above means? I have never see anything like that before, although I've been coding in C# for couple of years now... It is supposed to be a function, but I am not sure what is this < > and keyword where and new() at the end...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: Strange beasts you can see out there...

Comment: I don't think it's about the generics. I think it's about the type constraints. Well you only say the type `TResponse` must be a subclass of `IModbusMessage` or whatever that is, and there must be a constructor that takes no arguments. In many cases this means you want to construct new objects of `TResponse` in your class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx) on the TResponse generic type which implements the interface IModbusMessage and has a parameterless constructor.

> **where T : (interface name)** The type argument must be or implement the
>   specified interface. Multiple interface constraints can be specified.
>   The constraining interface can also be generic.
>
> **where T : new()** The type argument must have a public parameterless
>   constructor. When used in conjunction with other constraints, the
>   new() constraint must be specified last.

Also, as others have pointed out, I recommend you read the generics docs (pointed to by SLaks in the comments).

Comment: I doubt the OP has the prerequisite knowledge to understand your answer.

Answer (score 4):

What it implies is `TResponse` should be of type implementing the interface `IModbusMessage`

and `new()` implies of providing a default parameterless constructor.

I think you should better start off reading about [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Where: new() is the Generics Constructor Constraint

generic type parameter TResponse  must support a public default constructor.

check this for detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

it is a generic method.  the  specifies the type or family of objects that the method can work with.  The where clause is a constraint that says TReponse must implement the IModbusMessage interface, and that it must be able to be instantiated with the new keyword.